# limit of 16384 columns in excel 2016 pivot table

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table, limit, excel-2016

After the last Office 2016 update this error pops-out whenever I want to use a field in the column in the pivot table. I filter the data, so only 6 items remain, yet still cannot be placed into to the columns due to this limitation. Perhaps because the full data set has too many, irrespective of the data filtering.

As I use the Access for data handling, the temporal workaround is to limit the source SQL to the filter applied and than refresh the pivot table. The field can be placed into the columns and remain there even after the restrain on the source SQL is removed. Moving the field to rows and columns again triggers the error again.

Perhaps this might help someone to solve an issue on the spot, but does anyone knows how to fix this permanently ?

EDIT: so the permanent workaround is quite simple - I just place the field in the rows instead of columns, which is not constrained, then apply the filter and yes, it can be moved into the columns now.

Comment: Put it in the rows area, and turn your monitor sideways. ;-)

Other than that, no way round as far as I know.

Comment: Filtering has no relevance. The data has to be there before it can be filtered. The fact you end up only seeing 6 items just means that all of the others aren't shown; it doesn't make them magically disappear. (You can test that yourself; filter to see the 6, and then remove the filter and the data is still there.)